# Symfony FPNTagBundle loadTagging

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions

I use FPNTagBundle so that my users are able to add tags to a fact sheet. 
I got no problem for save my tags but i don't understand what i have to do for retrieve associated tags. 
I thought i had to use:

`$tagManager->loadTagging($factsheet);`

but it always return null.